# Intuitive approach to C array exercise from "the Book". [ex1-13]

Tags: c, arrays

I want to create a symbolic histogram from the input of the user detailing the word count of their paragraph's:

I am trying to find the len's of each word and log it in an array (++ for every word that is 1-3 letters, 3-5, etc.) and then print them out.

```
/* Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input. It is easy to draw the histrogram with bars, horizontal; a vertical oreientation is more challenging */
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int wordCountHistogram[5];
    int len = -1;
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++len;
        if (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == ' '){
            if (0 <= len <= 3)
                ++wordCountHistogram[0];

            if (4 <= len <= 6)
                ++wordCountHistogram[1];

            if (7 <= len <= 8)
                ++wordCountHistogram[2];

            if (9 <= len <= 13)
                ++wordCountHistogram[3];

            if (len > 14)
                ++wordCountHistogram[4];

            /*if (12 <= len <= 14)
                wordCountHistogram[5]++;

            if (14 <= len < 15)
                wordCountHistogram[6]++;

            if (16 <= len < 17)
                wordCountHistogram[7]++;

            if (17 <= len < 18)
                wordCountHistogram[8]++;

            if (19 <= len < 9999)
                wordCountHistogram[9]++;
        */
            printf("%d", len);
            len = -1;
    }
}

    for(int i = 0; i < 5 ;i++){
        printf("%d \n",wordCountHistogram[i]);
        for(int n = wordCountHistogram[i];n >= 0;n--){//Histogram sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
            printf("+");}
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

I know the "symbolic" lengths are being recorded as per the print I know wish to log each len recorded into its respective portion of the array (increase the array subscript value by 1] and then print out the histogram from such data. I am getting a rather funky error though and this causes the histogram to print out incorrectly as a result.

I know there is some funky issues with the print function put still the heart of the issue lies in the assigning of the wordCountHistogram.

Comment: I believe when I try printing the array (which is just the count of the word len's - more like a tally - I am getting memory addresses).

Comment: Can you show the error you're receiving?

Comment: Consider using math instead of a pile of `if` statements: `wordCountHistogram[length / 4]` for example, or `int spot = length / 4; if (spot > 4) { spot = 4 }` or something like that.

Comment: `if (0 <= len <= 3)` is not valid C syntax for checking if a variable is within a range. What that actually does is compare 0 and `len`. The result of that comparison is either 0 or 1. Then it proceeds to compare 0 or 1 to 3. Since 0 and 1 are both less than or equal to 3, the condition is always true.

Comment: Use a function to identify the values.

Comment: "A rather funky error" is not a useful description for anyone. Is it a compiler error? runtime error? Can you describe it? Narrow it down?

Comment: Getchar returns an `int`, for a reason!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things:

1. You need to initialize your histogram array to 0:

   ```
   int wordCountHistogram[5] = {0};
   ```

   Expressions like `0 <= len <= 3` don't work the way you expect - you need to use `0 <= len && len <= 3`

   You can use the `isspace` function (declared in `ctype.h`) to check if a character is whitespace:

   ```
   if ( isspace( c ) )
   {
     // update histogram
   }
   ```

   It's probably a good idea to abstract the binning operation out into a separate function, like so:

   ```
   int bin( int len )
   {
     if ( 0 <= len && len <= 3 )
       return 0;
     if ( 4 <= len && len <= 6 )
       return 1;
     if ( 7 <= len && len <= 8 )
       return 2;
     ...
   }
   int main( void )
   {
     ...
     if ( isspace( c ) )
       ++wordCountHistogram[ bin( len ) ];
     ...
   }
   ```

   Note - `c` should be declared as an `int`, not `char` - `getchar()` returns an `int`.  

   You'll want to add some sanity checks to make sure `bin` isn't returning a value out of range for your array.

Comment: `c` should be an `int` for `isspace`/or for char a cast to unsigned char required.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: it should be an `int` for the result of `getchar()` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're not initializing your array, which leaves you assuming you're going to populate it with values. This can cause the array to have garbage in it when you ctrl+D to print out your '+' signs. I recommend defining it when you declare it:

```
int wordCountHistogram[5] = {0};
```

I made that change, along with changing your evaluations:

```
if ((0 <= len) && (len  <= 3))
```

& your program gave me a histogram.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @user3386109. I've updated to make my code compliant.